# why only the first row of data was plotted [GNUPlot]

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file `data.txt`, and data are as follows.

```
352 0.523240374 0.522909505 0.523471053
450 0.521095585 0.518197521 0.521120231
571 0.514979782 0.517518353 0.517105300
856 0.517216354 0.517600585 0.515035365
1259 0.514126520 0.514697120 0.514651830
2302 0.510628639 0.510990627 0.511418731
5276 0.507016704 0.507616124 0.505787979
```

And I wrote a gnuplot script `plot.gpl`, the code is

```
set term pdf enhanced font "Sans, 12"    
set grid 
set xlabel "Num of Cell"
set xrange [0:5500]

set ylabel "Numerical result"
set yrange [0.5:0.53]

set output "pic.pdf"  
file = "data.txt"
plot file u 1:2 with linespoints ls 1 lw 0.1 ps 0.4 title "M11",\
     file u 1:3 with linespoints ls 2 lw 0.1 ps 0.4 title "M22",\
     file u 1:4 with linespoints ls 3 lw 0.1 ps 0.4 title "M33"
```

Then I typed the command `gnuplot plot.gpl`, a pdf file was generated, but only the first row of `data.txt` was plotted.

I tried to modify the format of `data.txt`, but failed.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

PS: Windows 10 Home, MSYS2: Mingw-w64 64 bit, gnuplot 5.2.0

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The data plots nicely. Could you please attach an image of your output? Do you get some error message? Do you mean only "M11" is plotted and "M22" and "M33" are missing?

Comment: Okay, I uploaded the figure I got, see the `PIC I GOT` on the top. @theozh

Comment: Does it plot ok if you use a gui terminal? Also, you might try include a `set out` after you plot it to ensure the file gets closed properly.

Comment: looks like you only have one line of data. Do you maybe have a text file which has been created on MacOS? Could you check your line end character? Is it `\n` (LF) (Linux) or `\r\n` (CR LF) (Windows) or `\r` (CR) (MacOs)? In the latter case you would get only the first row like you get.

Comment: Yes, this is the key. Convert 'data.dat' into `Windows(CR LF)`, and then it plots well. Thank you very much, @theozh. Also @matt.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of not letting this question appear unanswered. I guess according to SO "rules": no answers in comments.

Looks like you only have one line of data. Do you maybe have a text file which has been created on MacOS? Could you check your line end character? Is it `\n` (LF) (Linux) or `\r\n` (CR LF) (Windows) or `\r` (CR) (MacOs)? In the latter case you would get only the first row like you get.